# jquery zclip plugin not firing

Tags: jquery, zclip

I'm using the .on() method in delegation to bind a button click to the zclip plugin like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#copy-button", function () {
        $(this).zclip({
            path: "http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf",
            copy: function () {
                var text = 'copied text';
                return text;
            }
       })
    })
})
```

for the life of me, I cannot get anything copied to the clipboard, anyone have advice?

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sTa32/

Answer (score 0):

Your path includes nothing . Change your path to this for example: http://www.hurtwood.demon.co.uk/Fun/copter.swf

And you need to add some css for the view for it's very small

Comment: this is my path, no?? path: "http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf"

Comment: I know what your path is. I said the path that you entered includes nothing. I entered a example path